# Add dynamic varible to form/model in Yii

Tags: php, yii, yii-cformmodel

Please help, how i can add dynamic varible in Yii CFormModel?

```
private function magic($name, $value) {
    $this->$name = $value;
}
```

or

```
$form = new FormGenerate($attributes);
$form->temp = '1';
```

Show me Exception "Undetermined property" =(

Answer (score 0):

In your class try something like this

```
class Test
{
    public function __construct($x)
    {
        $this->{$x} = "dynamic";
    }
}

$a = new Test("bar");
print $a->bar;
```

try changing your

```
$this->$name
```

to

```
$this->{$name}
```

to see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

I create varible $_params;

And

```
public function __get($name)
    {
        if (isset($this->_params[$name])) {
            return $this->_params[$name];
        }

        return parent::__get($name);
    }


    public function __set($name, $value)
    {
        if (isset($this->_params[$name])) {
            $this->_params[$name] = $value;
        } else {
            parent::__set($name, $value);
        }
    }
```

It's work =)